# Listing rows with a WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, select

I am struggling with a SQL query that lists hosts that are offline.

**Problem**

The problem occurs when I need to list hosts that don't have any ports open (status = 0), so looking at the table at the bottom it should just list 192.168.1.2, however it lists all of the hosts.

I have tried many queries + sub queries with no luck yet, I would be grateful if you can tell me where I am going wrong and let me know what the correct query is. Thank you.

```
MariaDB [scanner]> SELECT DISTINCT ports.ip_add FROM ports WHERE ports.status = FALSE;
+-------------+
| ip_add      |
+-------------+
| 192.168.1.1 |
| 192.168.1.2 |
| 192.168.1.3 |
+-------------+
```

**Similar Working Query**

This query lists all hosts that have a least one port open (status = 1), great.

```
MariaDB [scanner]> SELECT DISTINCT ports.ip_add FROM ports WHERE ports.status = TRUE;
+-------------+
| ip_add      |
+-------------+
| 192.168.1.1 |
| 192.168.1.3 |
+-------------+
```

**Table**

```
MariaDB [scanner]> SELECT * FROM ports LIMIT 9;
+--------+-------------+----------+------------+---------------------+
| id     | ip_add      | port     | status     | probe_meta          |
+--------+-------------+----------+------------+---------------------+
|      1 | 192.168.1.1 |       22 |          1 | 2016-03-29 00:01:00 |
|      2 | 192.168.1.1 |       21 |          1 | 2016-03-29 00:02:00 |
|      3 | 192.168.1.1 |       23 |          1 | 2016-03-29 00:03:00 |
|      4 | 192.168.1.2 |       22 |          0 | 2016-03-29 00:05:00 |
|      5 | 192.168.1.2 |       21 |          0 | 2016-03-29 00:06:00 |
|      6 | 192.168.1.2 |       23 |          0 | 2016-03-29 00:07:00 |
|      7 | 192.168.1.3 |       22 |          1 | 2016-03-29 00:09:00 |
|      8 | 192.168.1.3 |       21 |          0 | 2016-03-29 00:10:00 |
|      9 | 192.168.1.3 |       23 |          0 | 2016-03-29 00:11:00 |
+--------+-------------+----------+------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One other way of doing this would be to aggregate the `status` column by `ip_addr`, where the total is equal to zero.

The test-bed:

```
CREATE TABLE `ports`
(
    `id` INT NOT NULL
    , `ip_add` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
    , `port` INT NOT NULL
    , `status` BIT NOT NULL
    , `probe_meta` DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO `ports` 
VALUES (1, '192.168.0.1', 22, 1, '2016-03-21 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO `ports` 
VALUES (1, '192.168.0.2', 22, 0, '2016-03-21 00:01:00');

INSERT INTO `ports` 
VALUES (1, '192.168.0.3', 22, 1, '2016-03-21 00:02:00');

INSERT INTO `ports` 
VALUES (1, '192.168.0.3', 22, 0, '2016-03-21 00:03:00');
```

The query:

```
SELECT ip_add
FROM `ports`
GROUP BY ip_add
HAVING SUM(status) = 0;
```

The results:

[image]

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8307/1)

Comment: If the `status` possible values are only 0 and 1, `HAVING MAX(status)=0` would also work.

Comment: Both clever solutions (more clever than mine :-)

Comment: [`BIT_OR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-or) would be a... bit more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL syntax is not my expertise, but this is the logical way to do it in T-SQL, so you get how you need to filter:

```
select distinct ip_add 
from ports 
where status = 0
and ip_add not in 
(
    select ip_add 
    from ports 
    where status = 1
    and ip_add is not null
)
```

This is the quick and dirty way, although there are more efficient ways to do it if the dataset is large, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you describe is known as relational division. In mathematics you could say something like: `FORALL x: p(x)`. This however is not possible to express in SQL, so we will have to transform the formulation of the problem. One common way is to say that: `NOT EXISTS x:NOT p(x)` which can be expressed in SQL. However, in your case it's probably easier to just count the ports with status 0 and compare with the total number of ports:

```
SELECT ports.ip_add 
FROM ports
GROUP BY ports.ip_add
HAVING COUNT(1) = COUNT(case when ports.status = 0 THEN 1 END);
```

Comment: Lennart thank you for the explanation, this helps.

Comment: `SUM(NOT ports.status)` would be more elegant in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @DávidHorváth smaller but less readable. And non-standard as it would only work in MySQL (and SQLite), nowhere else. The `CASE` expression is much more clearer to read and understand, at least for me.

Comment: @DávidHorváth in the I of the beholder I guess :-) Personally I'm not to found of mixing  boolean operators and integers. Another option might be: `COUNT(NULLIF(ports.status,1))`

Comment: @rwcommand, I like Max Vernons answer and ypercubeᵀᴹ comment better than my answer. Feel free to accept that one instead if you agree.

Comment: "This however is not possible to express in SQL.." Well, it depends on *which* SQL you mean: MySQL's: [`BIT_OR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-or), PG's [`bool_or`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html). ;) Can't find anything for SQL Server aside from the usual `MAX` hack, and Oracle doesn't even have a `BIT` or boolean type.

Comment: @jpmc26, Not sure I follow. How can you use bit operatiors to express universal quantification?

Comment: @Lennart are you available for private work, just modifying 2 SQL queries?

Comment: @Lennart A bitwise OR should be 0 if all the inputs are 0 and 1 if any of the inputs is 1, no? And MySQL uses 0 for `FALSE` and 1 for `TRUE`, right?

Comment: Relational division is much more general than this. I claimed that `FORALL x:p(x)` is not directly expressible in SQL.